# Do check-pointed flows between two parties share an Id?

Tags: corda

If a bilateral flow is kicked off between two parties, first checkpointed by Party A and then by Party B, do those flows share an Id?

e.g. - if I search through the checkpoints on both nodes, will I be able to match them?

Answer (score 2):

As of Corda 4.1 the checkpoint on two nodes will be different. The id of the checkpoint is based on the id of the `FlowStateMachine`. This state machine is not shared between the two nodes and therefore will have a unique id on each node.

Here is how checkpoints are added to the node vault: https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/release/4.1/node/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/node/services/persistence/DBCheckpointStorage.kt#L42